# Weird Pausing During HTTP Download ( Apache )

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

HTTP via Apache 2.4/Chrome over LAN: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGFo6.png

FTP via FileZilla Server/Chrome over LAN: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svo0v.png

HTTP downloads seem to go slow via localhost too.

I'm not quite sure what the problem is I've tried turning memory mapping and sendfile off and on.

Server: Windows XP Pro using Uniform Server, NetLimiter, Hamachi, Windows Firewall, No AV I should mention the DocumentRoot is hosted on an external usb HDD.

Client(s): Windows 7

I've noted the points it pauses: 4, 68, 132 ... 64n+4 MB (not sure if it's MiB or MB, just going off Chrome)

Comment: I had the same problem, after an upgrade to Uniform Server 8.5.2 with Apache 2.4.2 (from 2.4.1) it was all fixed, it was not a "hdd cache issue".

Answer (score 2):

> the DocumentRoot is hosted on an external usb HDD

Which just happens to have a 64MB cache ?

Comment: Actually you might be correct! (No idea about the starting 4MiB) I'll go Google, it's SATA3 USB 3.0 so maybe

Comment: Seagate Barracuda, 2TB, 3.5", SATA 3, 64MB, ST2000DL003

Comment: There you go, then :)

Comment: But what do I do to fix it as FTP is working fine?

Comment: Try different browsers, a different OS... start with wget :)

Comment: Seems to be server side, I wonder if Linux might be better?

Comment: >>>Just tested it also happens for the internal IDE drive.

Comment: Great catch, @adaptr!